# Is there a way to use VBA to change an Access query's field?

Tags: sql, vba, loops, ms-access, sql-update

I have an update query in MS Access that needs to select several columns, one at a time, from a separate table. Currently, the only way I am able to accomplish this is to edit the Access query using Design Mode (or SQL View), and change the value after each update to the next column name.

For example:

```
SELECT column1 from table;
SELECT column2 from table;
SELECT column3 from table;
```

So on and so forth...

I believe this can be accomplished with VBA, but I'm struggling to find any supporting documentation that would help accomplish this. Does anyone know what this operation would be called, if it is even possible?

Comment: Why would you not just select all the columns, and then use the VBA code to read each one? Also, you may want to include the code you are working with in your question.

Comment: Why must you select each column one at a time? Run update with an SQL statement constructed entirely within VBA instead of editing a query object. But yes, VBA using DAO and QueryDefs can modify query object.

Comment: You can do `CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myQuery").SQL = "SELECT foo FROM bar"`.